# Test of matrix commutativity

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to prove the following proposition:

> Let $A$ and $B$ square matrix of order $n$. If $AB = BA$, then $A^m B^n=B^n
>   A^m$ .

Using the power definition of matrices and matrices compatible, the proposition is proved, but it is too extensive.

Is there another way?

Comment: Since you've been a member for over 4 years, you may want to take the [tour of the site](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) and learn  [how to format mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) on Math SE if you need to do so. 
Furthermore, I suggest that you bookmark this [very useful MathJax link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) 
as a quick reference for future posts. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way is probably to show  (by induction on $k$) that if matrices $X$ and $Y$ satisfy $XY=YX$, then they satisfy $X^kY = YX^k$.

Then apply this twice: first, with $X=A$, $Y=B$, and $k=m$ to show that $A^mB = BA^m$. Second, with $X=B$, $Y=A^m$, and $k=n$ to show that $B^nA^m = A^mB^n$.

(You could also do the whole thing with a double induction on $m$ and $n$, but nobody likes double induction.)